# How to crawl YouTube Video comments?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, web-crawler, youtube-data-api

since YouTube Data API v2 no longer exists, you need extra permission from the user to read video comments (like permission youtube.force-ssl). There isn't any possibility to read video comments with the permission "youtube.readonly".

With Data API v2 ist was possible to read youtube video comments like this:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments

But how is it possible to get the youtube comments only with "youtube.readonly" permission? YouTube loads comments dynamically with ajax, so is it possible to crawl these comments?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: According to docs, `youtube.force-ssl` is required to access comments methods via YT Data API v3, so I guess you'll need to refresh your credentials and request this scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read top level comment by url, like you have said in your question

You can get it, but you need a youtube api key,(its free)

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId=NK94g7Qctuw&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

You do not have to get any access token, again if you want it to get from access token try to get refresh token like

```
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
```

Add above two line code in youtube api sample, you will get a auto refresh token. Hope it helps you.